# How to set default route parameter value in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to prevent additional redirect. Is there a way to set default parameter value in router config?

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/admin',
    element: <App/>,
    errorElement: <PageError/>,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        path: 'schedule/:date?',
        element: <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <PageCalendar />
        </React.Suspense>,
      },
```

Basically I want `"/admin/schedule/2023-05-11"` (current date) page to open if user tries to open `"/admin"` or `"/admin/schedule"` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to accomplish this *without* a redirect *somewhere* to get the UI synchronized with the correct URL path in the browser.

You can include a "catch-all" route that injects the current date and redirects to the default route.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

const ScheduleRedirect = () => {
  const date = /* compute formatted date, e.g. "2023-05-11" */
  return (
    <Navigate
      to={generatePath("/admin/schedule/:date", { date })}
      replace
    />
  );
};
```

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/admin',
    element: <App/>,
    errorElement: <PageError/>,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'schedule/:date',
        element: (
          <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <PageCalendar />
          </React.Suspense>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: <ScheduleRedirect />,
  },
]);
```

Comment: Tx, will try soon. I can't believe that one could start a library w/o tackling such a use case like default route param value. (But I can't find the very straightforward solution rather than something like you provided, I would expect route config option to achieve this)

Comment: @Rantiev If you contacted one of the RRD maintainers I'm somewhat certain the response would be something along the lines that "the route path is for specifying *what* can be matched, and not to provide what that *actual* values are, this is something implemented in user-land", e.g. by `Link` and `Navigate` components, and the `useNavigate` hook. If the data computation is cheap/trivial you *could* just render the redirect directly, something like ```{ path: "*", element: <Navigate to={`/admin/schedule/${getTodayDate()}`} replace /> }```.